# Can I change the label of an entry in the Finder sidebar?

Tags: finder

I have a couple folders in my Finder's sidebar. Since they're nested (on the actual file system), the names aren't very descriptive. Is there a way I can change the name of the entry in the sidebar without changing the actual name of the folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *was* possible in Tiger (As far as I can remember or Leopard) but on Snow Leopard, the “alias” is automatically resolved.

If you create an Alias on your desktop for a folder XYZ and then drag the Alias onto your sidebar, it’s automatically *resolved*. So it doesn’t seem to be possible to override this.